# Flutter Realtime database not showing

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve data from Realtime firebase. There is no error showing but still no data is showing on the screen. I'm trying to show the data as in a card as the picture below:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
  **List<Restaurant> restaurantsList = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    
    DatabaseReference restRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('restaurant');
    restRef.once().then((DataSnapshot snap){
      var keys = snap.value.keys;
      var data = snap.value;
      restaurantsList.clear();
      for(var key in keys){
        
        Restaurant rest = new Restaurant
        (
          data[key]['image'],
          data[key]['name'],
          data[key]['description'],
        );
        restaurantsList.add(rest);
      }
      setState(() {
        print('$restaurantsList');
        print('Length : $restaurantsList.length');
      });
    });
  }

  GridView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              primary: false,
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                childAspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
                    (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.25),
              ),
              itemCount: restaurantsList == null ? 0 :restaurantsList.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return GridProduct(
                  img: restaurantsList[index].image,
                  isFav: false,
                  name: restaurantsList[index].name,
                  rating: 5.0,
                  raters: 23,
                );
              },
            ),
```

Comment: Did you try setting the restaurant list in the `setState`? So: `setState(() { restaurantsList : 
 restaurantsList  })`. --- If that doesn't help: if you run the code in the debugger, does it get to `var keys = snap.value.keys`? If you step through the code from there on, does it read the values from the snapshot correctly?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get how to set the restaurantsList in the setState , and I don't think its getting the data from the firebase database , but its connected successfully

Comment: If you run the code in a debugger and set a breakpoint on `var keys = snap.value.keys;`, does it ever reach that breakpoint? If not, check the logging output of your app for error messages.

Comment: Thank you I did the breakpoint and I fixed it , I think the problem was with the emulator

Comment: Good to hear! 